# Library bt in Python - Obtaining the current security weights

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio, back-testing, bt

I am trying to use the library [bt](https://github.com/pmorissette/bt) to do backtest in Python. One of my strategies involves adding more capital to the portfolio periodically, and I would like the injected capital to be allocated according to the weights at that time. Basically my strategy looks something like this

```
contribution_stack = bt.AlgoStack(             
                bt.algos.RunMonthly(),
                bt.algos.CapitalFlow(100),
                UseCurrentWeight(),
                bt.algos.Rebalance()
            )
```

I do not rebalance my portfolio. I wonder whether what `UseCurrentWeight()` should look like? Thanks